# Dart Flutter - The named parameter 'begin' is required, but there's no corresponding argument

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a code like this :

```
import 'package:custom_timer/custom_timer.dart';
import 'package:fitness/core/service/date_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StartWorkoutTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  final int time;
  final bool isPaused;

  StartWorkoutTimer({
    required this.time,
    required this.isPaused,
  });

  @override
  _StartWorkoutTimerState createState() => _StartWorkoutTimerState();
}

class _StartWorkoutTimerState extends State<StartWorkoutTimer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.isPaused ? _createPauseText() : _createCountdownTimer();
  }

  Widget _createCountdownTimer() {
    return CustomTimer(
      from: Duration(seconds: widget.time),
      to: Duration(seconds: 0),
      onBuildAction: CustomTimerAction.auto_start,
      builder: (CustomTimerRemainingTime remaining) {
        return Text(
          "${remaining.minutes}:${remaining.seconds}",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _createPauseText() {
    final minutesSeconds = DateService.convertIntoSeconds(widget.time);
    return Text(
      "${minutesSeconds.minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${minutesSeconds.seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 17,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But it's showing an error like this :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lps4a.png)

Then it says that: Undefined name 'CustomTimerAction'.
and : The named parameter 'onBuildAction' isn't defined.

Can please someone help with this ?

Comment: `CustomTimer( begin:1, from: Duration(seconds: widget.time),
            to: Duration(seconds: 0),....` add begin parameter because it required in the constructor

Comment: `CustomTimer({Key? key, CustomTimerController? controller, required Duration begin, required Duration end, Widget animationBuilder(Widget)?, required Widget builder(CustomTimerRemainingTime), Widget? stateBuilder(CustomTimerRemainingTime, CustomTimerState)?, void onChangeState(CustomTimerState)?})
Creates a customizable timer.
const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CustomTimer](https://pub.dev/documentation/custom_timer/latest/custom_timer/CustomTimer-class.html) doesn't have the property `from` but [begin](https://pub.dev/documentation/custom_timer/latest/custom_timer/CustomTimer/begin.html). Like the error said, it is required. So for your case, you have to change `from` to `begin`. Also the property `onBuildAction` doesn't exist.

```
Widget _createCountdownTimer() {
    return CustomTimer(
      begin: Duration(seconds: widget.time),
      end: Duration(seconds: 0),
      builder: (CustomTimerRemainingTime remaining) {
        return Text(
          "${remaining.minutes}:${remaining.seconds}",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: i did add begin(from) and end(to) and it worked, thank you so much for your help!